# VueJS reading $root Ajax fetched data from within router-view returns undefined only when directly navigating to url

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm learning my ways around vuejs and decide to create an eshop-like webpage for practice.

I fetch all my data in one api call and want to have access to them from all my router-views, so I can pair the category name to the rest of the data.

What I currently do is fetch all my data on the `new Vue` `created` and then access it accordingly from all the router-views with `$root`.

This works great except when directly navigating to the url or refreshing the page.

From what I could find, it seems the `category` object is not yet loaded and returns `null`

This is obviously a timing issue, but I have not managed to find what needs to go where...

The `beforeRouteEnter` was my latest attempt to fix this issue

**My route**

```
const routes = [
        { path: '/category/:category', component : category}
    ]

    const router = new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: routes
    })
```

**Router View**

```
const category = {
        template: `<div>
                    <h1>{{$route.params.category}}</h1>
                    <b>{{category}}</b>
                </div>`,
        computed: {
            vueRoot: function(){
                return this.$root;
            },
            category: function() {
                    return this.$root.categories.filter(c => c.name === this.$route.params.category)[0]
                })
            },
        }
    }
```

**Main Vue**

```
var app = new Vue({
        router,
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            products: {},
            groups: {},
            categories: {}
        },
        methods: {
            goBack () {
                window.history.length > 1
                ? this.$router.go(-1)
                : this.$router.push('/')
            },
            fetchProducts: function(){
                $.get("/api/fetchv2.json", function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    app.products = data.products;
                    app.groups = data.groups;
                    app.categories = data.categories;
                }).fail(function(error) {
                    alert( "error" );
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        },
        created: function(){
            this.fetchProducts();
        },
        beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
            this.fetchProducts();
        }
    })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you initializing your data properties as objects (`categories: {}`)? Objects do not have a `filter` method.

Comment: That... is a very good question... And apparently it fixed everything! Would you like adding that as an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computed value in the category component is going to try to run when the category component is instantiated. Since your data is retrieved asynchronously, that means before the data is retrieved from the server, the computed will attempt to `filter` an empty object (because that is how `categories` is initialized).

Instead, initialize `categories` with an empty array `[]`.